# Force reader view in browser / Modify the content of all a tags in JS

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, dom-manipulation, firefox-reader-view

first time posting on here. Let me preface this by saying that I am not that well versed in JS yet.
I am trying to write a simple JavaScript script that forces reader view for clear viewing of a linked webpage (DOM manipulation). I was looking online for a good way to do this, and at first I thought Node.insertBefore() would be a good way, but I came to realize that this would create a new node instead of modifying the existing one, so I came to Stackoverflow to try and find a good way of doing this but I could not find a satisfying answer.

The way I want to go about it is modifying all a elements in the document to have 'about:reader?url=' before the URL, and after that is working, a check to see what browser the user is using, and modify the code to ensure the code is compatible with the users browser. Only here I found out that Chrome users require the manual enabling of an experimental flag, which will likely cause some trouble.

My code looks like this:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="parentElement">
    <a href="stackoverflow.com/questions">Click here</a>
</div>

    <script src="js\script.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var readerText = document.createTextNode('about:reader?url=');
var link = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

link.parentNode.insertBefore(readerText, link);


// Get the parent element
let parentElement = document.getElementById('parentElement')
// Get the parent's first child
let theFirstChild = parentElement.firstChild

// Create a new element
let newElement = document.createElement("div")

// Insert the new element before the first child
parentElement.insertBefore(newElement, theFirstChild)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, not only are code suggestions welcome, but also any knowledge about how different browsers approach reader view and if there is a feasible way to consistently force reader view in different browsers.
Thank you!
-Seraphym

Comment: I’m wondering about the use case of such an effort, what is the problem you are trying to solve, if users can switch to reading mode themselves.

Comment: Mozilla open sourced the library that generates the reading view: [Readability on GitHub](https://github.com/mozilla/readability). Might it be interesting to generate that view yourself instead of hacking around browsers’ current implementations? It’s not a stable API, after all.

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for your reply.

The issue is this: I would like to show internet pages for children ready to print, i.e. without all the visual clutter. Of course my I could embed the text after scraping it from the target sites, but that would lead to copyright issues. The challenge is to direct traffic to that website while ensuring a printable layout without stuff like navigation and page footers and such for the users (children). Is that doable at all somehow?

Comment: Usually you would use CSS to declare styles for printing, which hide navigation and other elements that are unwanted in print. Using [the `media` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style#attr-media), you can define a layout optimised for screen, and another one optimised for print. Might that be interesting?